# SQL Server, how to set the default collation to unicode?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, encoding

I've a WPF+WCF application which works good for now 2 years, but now they have one needs: They want to enter some data in the database, which isn't in the european alphabet(e.g. cyrillic).

The problem is that the database as a collation set to Latin1_General_CI_AS_WS, and when I store data in it(e.g. вмешательство), and retrieve them, I got some "??????" instead(When going in the SQL Server Management studio).

The rest of the application already knows working with other kind of alphabet(not for direction of reading, but not my direct problem).

So how can I set the collation to unicode, in an existing database? The collation field is in gray in the SQL Server management studio.

I'm using EntityFramework for all my communication with the database, and I also got those "????" if I retrieve any fields.

Comment: What is the data type in question? Collation isn't your problem.

Comment: I've not tested on all case, but mostly varchar(X) and text

Comment: There's your problem. It should be `nvarchar(x)` and `ntext`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is not collation, it is data type.

As noted in the comments, you are using `varchar(x)` and `text`. These types do not store unicode data. You need to be using `nvarchar(x)` and `ntext` instead. (if you are on SQL 2005 or newer, you should use `nvarchar(MAX)` instead of `ntext`)

Comment: Ouch, so I've to change the whole database type :/. Why use nvarchar(max) instead of ntext?

Comment: No, not the database type. The columns data type. And text/ntext are deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming version. nvarchar(max) works the same way as ntext.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't write it right. Thank you vor the text explanation. I've made some tests, but it seems it's still written with "??????" in the database. Is it necessary to generate again my EF object?

Comment: I refreshed my edmx and set "Unicode" to true on the modified field, but it doesn't change anything :(. Is there something special I should do on the model itself(POCO objects)

Comment: Edit: I refreshed badly the edmx, now that I had correctly refreshed it, AND put fields to Unicode=True in the edmx, I got my "вмешательство" :)